# Post bath - ferret full blown attacking other ferret!

Tags: behavior, aggression, dominance, ferrets, bathing

I have 2 jills that have lived together, for the most part, peacefully for the past 4 years. I have recently bathed them and used a new ferret shampoo that is lightly scented. After bathing, I did the usual thing of trying to help dry them off while they run around rubbing themselves on everything.

After they both became dry again, they started attacking each other, one more so than the other. One actually drew blood on the other's neck. I assumed it's down to scent, so I've tried rubbing some of their unwashed bedding on them - but that's not worked.

I've had to keep them separated for now, with one in the cage while the other is out. Any advice? I know ferrets play rough, but they've never drawn blood.